# Asus Xtion Pro sensor calibration or texture offset workaround

Tags: kinect

I'm using 2 of the sensors on the asus xtion pro (kinect knockoff), the RGB cam and the user data as a mask. Not sure if it's called user data, the other one that's not depth or color.

It works except for 2 issues:
[image]

When you combine the 2 textures together, the mask is actually slightly offset from the color texture, leaving an outline around the character of the background. I believe it's because the two sensors are simply shooting straight out and aren't calibrated, so one is 2" in real world space off from the other.

The second problem is a question about optimizing the mask edges. Is there any way to feather the edges around the character, or smooth based on the difference of neighboring pixels? I find that the edges really jump around on the edges of objects.

So, the shader I'm using to combine the base texture with the mask requires both textures to be the same size, so I can't simply resize it to be slightly smaller to get rid of the gap around the character.

I'm curious of how you would shrink the mask texture by a couple % and add more black around the edges, like if you resized the texture smaller than the rect it occupies, how could you fill in the perimeter with black?

I'm using Unity + OpenNI + Asus xtion pro sensor.   The mis-alignment ins't noticeable in most uses, but when doing something really precise it's not that accurate...

Any ideas or pointers? Looking for direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two Asus Xtion Pro sensors at the same time ? The 3 images on the left look like the scene, depth and rgb streams.

Which version of OpenNI are you using ? I haven't used OpenNI with Unity, but I assume you there are equivalent calls to the original API.

For OpenNI 1.5.x look into the [Alternative View Point Capability](http://kinectcar.ronsper.com/docs/openni/group__altviewpoint.html):

```
yourDepthGenerator.GetAlternativeViewPointCap().SetViewPoint(image);
```

For OpenNI 2.x it should be something like:

```
device.setDepthColorSyncEnabled(true);
```

If you want to calibrate between two sensors, it's [a bit more complicated](http://burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration).